# SQL Recover from .bak file with NOINIT

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

This will, hopefully, be a nice and quick question for someone out there. It continues from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396027/restoring-a-database-from-bak-file-on-another-machine).

I have a .BAK file that I'm trying to restore. The .BAK was created with the `NOINIT` argument, to try and save previous version, and so has newer data appended (as I understand it). I was wondering if this meant that - upon restore - restore would try to use an old version of the backup?

I.e. I have backed up the DB, added new tables to it, performed another full back-up and dropped the added tables. When I try to restore, I am not getting the 'new' tables back, is this because the restore is finding a version of the database in the .BAK which was created before the 'new tables'? If so, how can I specify to use the latest data?

EDIT: Apologies for not stating sooner, this is using an SQL Server database

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because by not specifying the `FILE` parameter of `RESTORE DATABASE`, it is defaulting to 1 which will be the 1st backup set on that media.  See the section on this page of [Specifying a Backup Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178615.aspx).

Instead of:

```
restore database YourDb
from disk = 'C:\yourpath\backupfile.bak';
go
```

You will want to do:

```
restore database YourDb
from disk = 'C:\yourpath\backupfile.bak'
with file = <n>;
go
```

Where `N` is the backup set number in the media.  `N` can be obtained from running [`RESTORE HEADERONLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178536.aspx) on the media.  The column you will be concerned with is `Position` to use with the `FILE` option.