# Display local variable in while loop

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a while loop that is running for days (bydesign) see related [Is there a limit to how many backups can be appended to a single file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/244787/21924)

I have a local variable that displays the loop count, when I run it in a query window I can display the count with `print @counter`

I am now running the while loop in a job, and I want to display the `@counter`value.  After some research I tried [RAISERROR (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql) which should display in the SQL error log, but it is not working.  I read [Using RAISERROR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms177497%28v%3dsql.105%29) I think I have the code correct, but not sure it can be used in While loop, with a local variable.

Create the database and prep it

```
USE [master]
GO
Create database T_test

USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [T_test] SET RECOVERY FULL WITH NO_WAIT
GO

BACKUP DATABASE T_test to disk= N'K:\Test\T_test.bak' with noinit --Create first full
GO
```

Try running in a query window to test

```
DECLARE @counter int
SET @counter = 0
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN 
BACKUP DATABASE [T_test] TO  
DISK = N'K:\Test\T_Test.diff' WITH  DIFFERENTIAL , NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  
NAME = N'T_Test-Diff Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION
SET @counter = @counter + 1;
RAISERROR(N'Count equals :%d', 16, 1, @counter );
print @counter 
END
```

Stop after a couple of loops and check the SQL logs and the query message

[image: T_Test dot jpeg]

The error is not in the SQL logs, but is displayed in the query message.

I don't think you can use `GO 5000000` with a local variable, at least in my attempts it resets every time it is re-declared.

How can I display the local variable in a while loop, real time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two extensions of [RAISERROR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that may help:

To write it to the error log:

```
DECLARE @msg NVARCHAR(1000) = N''
RAISERROR(@msg, 16, 1) WITH LOG;
```

To display it in the messages tab in "real time":

```
DECLARE @msg NVARCHAR(1000) = N''
RAISERROR(@msg, 16, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could write the value to a table. Something like

```
create LogTable(Counter int, When datetime);
```

You can query this table when you need to see the progress.

If you don't want to pollute a production database with this it could be created in TempDB. Note I do *not* mean create a `#temp` table. That would be visible to the backup job only. I mean a "real" table but in tempdb. It would be dropped on instance restart so [appropriate management routines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-procoption-transact-sql) must be put in place.