# Can I move SQL Server backup files on a running database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, backup

Our backup drive is filling up with TRN and BAK files. I have administrative privileges on the server, but I don't have a login to the database.

Can I move the oldest files off to somewhere else without causing service interruption? Which ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, yes, you can move the backup files.  Backup files are not in use by SQL Server once the associated backup is complete.  .BAK files are typically full or differential backups, and .TRN are typically transaction log backups, and they can all be moved.  It is certainly possible to use different file extensions for the backups, but it's not common.

Please be aware, though, that there may be other processes that use the backup files, such as log shipping or automated restores to non-production environments.  There is, of course, no way we can tell you what may be happening in your environment, so we can't tell you what might break if you move files.  If you are just moving the oldest files, then it's less likely you'll be interrupting something.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the backups are not actively being written to, you can delete, copy, or move them without impacting SQL.

You can do this to .bak or .trn or .dif

Beware that during the backup process you can use any extension you want like .WhatEver

It doesn't really mater what extension they have, same rules apply.

If the files have extensions .mdf or .ndf or .ldf they are not backups, don't do anything to them.

You should work with the business to define how long backups need to be kept for. If you have 2 year old backups, and there is no need to keep them longer then 30 days, don't move them delete them.

Also keep in mind that if there is a disaster, backups on the same hardware as the server are going to be gone too.

So:

Can you move them? = Yes probably

Should you move them? = That is a business decision, talk to the people who own the data.

As a rule you probably want to leave the backups taken in the last day to week on the server, this varies with your DR requirements.

If there is only one full backup file because the backup is using  `NOINIT` then see this post [Is there a limit to how many backups can be appended to a single file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/244787/21924)